# SaltStack - Touch and 666 /var/db/ntp-kod for Mojave 10.14

Tags: macos, salt-stack

Bit confused how I can implement this request in Salt.

I need to touch and 666 /var/db/ntp-kod file. I'm on 10.14.
Can we do it via file.managed?

Can you guys help me with full code here for this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use file.managed. The magic is to set `replace: False`. See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed

```
replace: True
    If set to False and the file already exists, the file will not be modified even if changes would otherwise be made. Permissions and ownership will still be enforced, however.
```

**edit**: You need to touch it, so just add `contents: ''`, but I wonder if you really looked the documentation page

Comment: Thanks daks. I went through lot of SaltStacks docs. I manged to create the formula and it worked perfectly.